# Stream to save in map name and count of objects signed with that name

Tags: java, dictionary, java-stream

I have a list of objects Book:

```
class Book{
Boolean state; 
String reader;
}
```

I need a stream, which will save to `Map<String, Integer>`  reader as key and count of books that reader holds. `State` says if book is currently lent or not.
I began with something like this:

```
Map<String, Integer> readers = bookRepository.getAllBooks().stream()
            .filter(Book::getState)
            .map(Book::getLastReader)
```

but I don't know how to complete it.

Answer (score 2):

You're done halfway: That is filter your book which is lent, after that you need to `groupingBy`:

```
// Need to import static Collectors.groupingBy, Collectors.counting
Map<String, Long> readers = bookRepository.getAllBooks().stream()
        .filter(Book::getState)
        .collect(groupingBy(Book::getReader, counting()));
```

Note that: `groupingBy` return `Long` type for counting.

Comment: "Note that: groupingBy return Long type for counting.". you don't always have to use the `counting()` collector. if you want the map values to be an integer instead of long then use  `Collectors.summingInt(e -> 1)`

Answer (score 0):

To finish off what you’ve started simply chain the following operation to the `map` operation:

```
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), 
            Collectors.summingInt(e -> 1)));
```

This will yield a `Map<String, Integer>` as you’ve mentioned.